# How to configure LDAP in Keycloak dynamically

Tags: java, ldap, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I am using Keycloak as UAA for my project, and I am able to create a new realm in keycloak dynamically via java code. Now i would like to add LDAP support for the relam which is created in keycloak.Is there any option to do it dynamically using java ?

I able to drill down and identified the attributes that i need to set. basically i created ComponentRepresentation object with all ldap values and added into the realm,

```
ComponentRepresentation ldapComponentRep = new ComponentRepresentation();

String componentId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

ldapComponentRep.setId(componentId);
ldapComponentRep.setName("testldap");
ldapComponentRep.setProviderId("testldap");
ldapComponentRep.setParentId("realmname");
ldapComponentRep.setProviderType("org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProvider");

MultivaluedHashMap config = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();

config.putSingle("fullSyncPeriod", "-1");
config.putSingle("pagination", "true");
config.putSingle("connectionPooling", "true");
config.putSingle("usersDn", "o=758ldifojencdjks,dc=test,dc=com");
config.putSingle("cachePolicy", "DEFAULT");
config.putSingle("useKerberosForPasswordAuthentication","false");
config.putSingle("importEnabled","true");
config.putSingle("enabled","true");
config.putSingle("bindCredential","*********");
config.putSingle("usernameLDAPAttribute","uid");
config.putSingle("bindDn","uid=ldap.connector,ou=Users,o=758ldifojencdjks,dc=test,dc=com");
config.putSingle("changedSyncPeriod","-1");
config.putSingle("vendor","other");
config.putSingle("uuidLDAPAttribute","entryUUID");
config.putSingle("allowKerberosAuthentication","false");
config.putSingle("connectionUrl","ldap://ldap.test.com:389");
config.putSingle("syncRegistrations","false");
config.putSingle("authType","simple");
config.putSingle("debug","false");
config.putSingle("searchScope","2");
config.putSingle("useTruststoreSpi","ldapsOnly");
config.putSingle("priority","1");
config.putSingle("trustEmail","false");
config.putSingle("userObjectClasses","inetOrgPerson, organizationalPerson");
config.putSingle("rdnLDAPAttribute","uid");
config.putSingle("editMode","READ_ONLY");
config.putSingle("validatePasswordPolicy","false");
config.putSingle("batchSizeForSync","1000");

ldapComponentRep.setConfig(config);

keycloak.realms().realm("realmname").components().add(ldapComponentRep).getStatus();
```

The output of the last line 201 but there is no exception and the configuration are not saved either.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes finally I am able to create LDAP config dynamically, there was a wrong input passed in the providerId

```
ldapComponentRep.setName("testldap");   
ldapComponentRep.setProviderId("testldap");
```

it should be as below,

```
ldapComponentRep.setProviderId("ldap");
```